# Unable to access Rest-Resource request url

Tags: java, rest, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

In Jira Plugin development, i have created a rest resource class at location - "[FOLDER]/Src/Main/JAVA/com.company.jira.plugin.REST/PlanIssuesRestResources"

Now, when i try to access below url in browser then,

http://[host]:2990/jira/rest/auth/1/PlanIssuesRestResource

then it shows below error message in browser:

```
<status-code>404</status-code>
<message>null for uri: http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/auth/1/PlanIssuesRestResource
</message>
</status>
```

My Rest resource class is looks as below:

```
@Path("/message")
public class PlanIssuesRestResource {
 @GET
        @AnonymousAllowed
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
       @Path("/{key}")
      public Response getMessageFromPath(@PathParam("key") String key)
        {
            return Response.ok(new PlanIssuesResourceModel(key,     getMessageFromKey(key))).build();
        }
```

How can i access this URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found,

Follow below link for details about Rest resource URL composition:

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/REST+Plugin+Module

Below is related communication ticket at answers.atalssianc.com.
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/156650/development-in-jira-plugin-how-to-use-rest-api-in-velocity-template-through-json

Thank You
Dhaval Soni